# How to insert mysql fetched data again into database table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert

I've fetch these groceries product values from database. Customer can enter their quantity in that appropriate textbox. Now, I want to store these values again into database table with quantity value. How can I do that? I can insert the data using input textfield. But, Here I have the values from database.

How to insert these data again?

```
    <form name="form1" action="" method="post" class="groceries-form">
        <?php 
        $sql_records = "SELECT * FROM ".tbl_groceries."";
        $records = mysql_query($sql_records,$CN);
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($records))
        {
         ?>
            <tr class="itemrow">
                 <td style="text-align: center;"><?=$rows['ID']?></td>
                 <td class="name"><span code="18" class="iname" type="text"><?=$rows['item_title']?></span></td>
                 <td class="qty"><input maxlength="2" class="tqty orderbox" type="text" name="quantity"></td>
                 <td class="qty1"><?=$rows['price']?></td>
                 <td class="qty1"><?=$rows['mrp']?></td>
                 <td class="qty1"><?=$rows['savings']?></td>
                 </tr>
   <?php } ?>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit"/>
         </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### I recommend you using PDO, or you could get problems with mysql injections.

#### [PHP: PDO - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

If you want to still use the same way as in your code (which is not recommended), you basically do just the same as you did with the inputs. The post/get values is variables just like those you have outputted from database right there. Just insert those values like you did with the input values (which appear as variables in php) into the database.

#### Edit:

I think i misunderstood your question a little bit, but you should check out PDO anyways! :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to send the data to another php processing page, along with add a table for the new data to go into, foreach table column that isn't the quantity, you will need to add hidden inputs in the form such as:
    `<input type="hidden" name="itemid" value="<?=$rows['id']?>">`
These are some fields you may want to include in the new table:
ItemID
ItemPrice
ItemQuantity
CustomerID (If you have got a customerID or name to provide

Using the following php code you should be able to insert the new data into this other mysql table

```
<?php
$itemid = $_POST['itemid'];
$itemprice = $_POST['itemprice'];
$itemquantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$customerid = $_POST['customerid'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO newtablename (itemid, itemprice, itemquantity, customerid) VALUES ('$itemid','$itemprice','$itemquantity','$customerid')");
?>
```

(Don't forget to connect to database)

Answer (score -1):

send the form to a php file that preforms an Update sql query, passing the values you need to create that query for each record.

[Mysql update with w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp)

Comment: No, I don't want to update the data. I want to insert the data again in new table..

Comment: Linking to external data source is not good practice as an answer as it can vanish. Instead you should write the answer here (for future readers) or use the comments for external links